# NextJS 13, is it possible to use NextJS cache as a normal cache database?

Tags: javascript, caching, next.js, next.js13

In the docs of [Next.js 13](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#data-cache), it says that you can use data-cache in fetch in a server component to cache data.

But, is it possible to save a dynamic javascript object (an object created by the application itself) on the same datastore that saves the API response caches?